# Unable to observe the Data posted From ViewModel to Activity During Test Case

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-livedata

I am writing the Unit Test Case using the Roboelectric , basically I want to test my activity class UI ,but data coming from viewmodel and it's observed in activity and then it's set to the UI also the inside observe the method is private in my activity class. So I have two open point :

1. How to test the private function of activity/fragment from Unit Test Case

Or

2. If I am able to trigger the observe method of livedata in activity then my UI will set and able to write the UT test cases ,but livedata observe is not getting triggered in activity.

Currently , I have tried many things but unable to figure out the issue , or I am missing something in understanding .
Inside ViewModel, the data is posted but after that inside activity the livedata is not observed.

Test Class:

```
@Test
    fun theRobotTest()
    {
        supplierVM.getSummary()//API Call

        supplierVM.orderSummaryDetails
            .getOrAwaitValue() // getting data from Live Data
        
        val lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry(mock(LifecycleOwner::class.java))
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
        scenario.apply {
            supplierVM.orderSummaryDetails.observe({ lifecycle }) {
              
                assertEquals(
                    it?.merchantId, // able to access the data 
                    paySupplierActivityBinding().amountView.text.toString() // coming blank
                )
            }
        }
}
```

ViewModel Class://able to post the data on mutubale livedata

```
fun getSummary() {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            supplierRepo.getSupplierOrderSummary(
                getInstance().mid.string(),getInstance().storeId
            )
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    onAPISuccess(it)
                }, Error { httpCode, status, message ->
                 
                })
        )
    }

    private fun onAPISuccess(res: MasterResponse?) {
        _mDetails.postValue(res) //able to post the data here
    }
```

Activity Snapshot: initObservers called from onCreate()

Unable to observe the livedata after the value is posted from ViewModel

```
private fun initObservers() {
        supplierOrderSummaryModel.getSummary().observe(this) { handleSummeryDetails(it) }
    }
    private fun handleSummeryDetails (it: MasterResponse?){
        //do something
    }
```